# In WPF two tabs gets selected if I run following application on Window's 10 machine

Tags: wpf, .net-4.6

If I run below application on window's 7 system it works fine but if i run it on window's 10 machine two tabs 'tab 1 ' and 'tab 2' gets selected after clicking 'Add' button. Window's 10 have .net 4.6 framework installed. I am never able to select 'tab 1' again.

```
namespace TabControlTest
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    using System.Windows.Input;


    public  class MainWindowViewModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private TabItem _selectedItem;

        private TabItem _homePageTabItem;

        private ObservableCollection<TabItem> _tabItems;
          private IList<TabItem> _tabBackingList;

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
             _homePageTabItem = new TabItem
                                       {
                                           Header = "Tab 1",
                                           Content = "Tab 1 Content",
                                           IsSelected = true,
                                           IsChecked = true
                                       };


             _tabBackingList = new List<TabItem> { _homePageTabItem };

            TabItems = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>(_tabBackingList);
            AddCommand = new RelayCommand(AddTabs);
        }

        public ICommand AddCommand { get; private set; }

        public ObservableCollection<TabItem> TabItems
        {
            get
            {
                return _tabItems;
            }

            set
            {
                if (_tabItems != value)
                {
                    _tabItems = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public TabItem SelectedItem
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedItem;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_selectedItem != value)
                {
                    _selectedItem = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        private void AddTabs(object param)
        {
              _tabBackingList.Clear();
              _tabBackingList.Add(_homePageTabItem);

             var item2 = new TabItem { Header = "Tab 2", Content = "Tab 2 Content", IsSelected = true, IsChecked = true };
            var item3 = new TabItem { Header = "Tab 3", Content = "Tab 3 Content", IsSelected = false };
            _tabBackingList.Add(item2);
            _tabBackingList.Add(item3);
            TabItems = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>(_tabBackingList);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}


namespace TabControlTest
{
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Input;

    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
        private readonly Action<object> _execute;

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        {
            _execute = execute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            if (_canExecute == null) return true;

            return _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    }
}

namespace TabControlTest
{
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

    public class TabItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _isSelected;

        private bool _isChecked;
        public string Header { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get
            {
                return _isSelected;
            }

            set
            {
                if (_isSelected != value)
                {
                    _isSelected = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }


        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get
            {
                return _isChecked;
            }

            set
            {
                if (_isChecked != value)
                {
                    _isChecked = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace TabControlTest
{
    using System.Windows;

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
        }
    }
}

<Window x:Class="TabControlTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:tabControlTest="clr-namespace:TabControlTest"
                     xmlns:uxc="http://schemas.thermofisher.com/2013/UXLibrary/Controls"

        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Add" Margin="5" Grid.Row="0" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" ></Button>
        <TabControl  Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding TabItems}" >
            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type tabControlTest:TabItem}">
                    <Button Content="{Binding Content}"></Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Interesting - I cannot find an explicit question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the behavior in Window 7, but it should yield the same error.
As you can see with this implementations, you are replacing the entire source of tabs inside your ICommand via:

```
TabItems = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>(_tabBackingList);
```

So it means your "Tab 1" instance is not there and expectedly the UI won't get updated.

Should be:

```
 var item2 = new TabItem { Header = "Tab 2", Content = "Tab 2 Content", IsSelected = true, IsChecked = true };
 var item3 = new TabItem { Header = "Tab 3", Content = "Tab 3 Content", IsSelected = false };

 //_tabBackingList.Add(item2);
 //_tabBackingList.Add(item3);
 //TabItems = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>(_tabBackingList);

 TabItems.Add(item2);
 TabItems.Add(item3);
```

Comment: Sample code is extracted from big application. It works fine on window'7 but same code doesn't run on window's 10. As in AddCommand after clearing backing list I am adding back 'Tab 1' then Tab 2 and Tab 3. In window's 10 Tab 1 and Tab 2 both get selected and there is no way I can navigate to 'Tab 1'.

In window'10 If I clear TabItems and then assign new collection it works fine.
TabItems.Clear();
TabItems = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>(_tabBackingList);